# MySQL Join Return Null

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, union-all

I have two tables

```
Table_1
id|subject_code|subject_id
 1|Test1       |1
 2|Test2       |2
 3|Test3       |3

Table2
id|subject_id|grade|status
 1|1         |5.00 |Fail
 2|3         |2.25 |Pass
```

Now, I want to create a query that will return the following,

```
Table3
subject_code|grade|status
Test1       |5.00 |Fail
Test2       |NULL |NULL
Test3       |2.25 |Pass
```

I have read about combining left join and union all but I am lost on how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a left join, like this::

```
Select 
DISTINCT(table1.subject_code), 
grade, 
status

from table1 
LEFT join table2 on (table1.subject_id=table2.subject_id)
```

Comment: This returns identical rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT subject_code, grade, status 
FROM Table_1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.subject_id = t2.subject_id;
```

Comment: This returns identical rows.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a simple LEFT JOIN would do the trick :

`SELECT Table_1.subject_code, Table2.grade, Table2.status
FROM Table_1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.subject_id = Table_1.subject_id`;

Comment: This returns identical rows.